# Magento resave all products that are in in price table

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products, script, shell

We face an issue that not all products with prices are saved in the **catalog_product_index_price** table.

So we want to resave all products that are not in the **catalog_product_index_price**.

How can we achieve that?

My current code just resave all products:

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class Resave_Products extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
            echo $product->getSku() . '';
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Resave_Products();
$shell->run();?>
```

Comment: Could this be solved by reindexing the catalog_product_price index?  Usually that is one of the fastest ones.

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reindexing **catalog_product_price** should do the trick

If that's not the case, I think you have a real big problem with your catalog data. Anyways, what you're asking could be something like this

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Mage_Shell_FixPrices extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    protected $_resource = null;

    protected function getResource()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_resource)) {
            $this->_resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        }
        return $this->_resource;
    }

    protected function hasPriceData($productId)
    {
        $readConnection = $this->getResource()->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = $readConnection->select()
            ->from($this->getResource()->getTableName('catalog_product_index_price'))
            ->where('entity_id = ?', $productId);

        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        if (!empty($results)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $readConnection = $this->getResource()->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = $readConnection->select()
            ->from($this->getResource()->getTableName('catalog_product_entity'));

        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            if (! $this->hasPriceData($row['entity_id'])) {
                $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);
                try {
                    $p->save();
                    echo $p->getSku() . " fixed\n";
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "error " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                }
                $p->clearInstance();
            }
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_FixPrices();
$shell->run();
```